# Getting error "the device id is invalid" when adding device to Azure IoT Hub with AddDeviceAsync method

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-iot-hub

I have used RegisterManager.AddDevicesAsync method when adding a device as device id includes "I (letter)" to Azure IoT hub in my project. And the exception occurred. Has the device id any constraint about this issue?

```
public async Task AddDeviceAsync(DeviceConfig deviceConfig)
    {
        try
        {
            DeviceStatus status;
            if (!Enum.TryParse(deviceConfig.Status, true, out status))
            {
                status = DeviceStatus.Enabled;
            }

            var d = new Device(deviceConfig.DeviceId)
            {
                Status = status
            };

            await this.registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(d);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            throw new EVCException(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
        await this.deviceManager.AddDeviceAsync(new DeviceConfig { DeviceId = "ILICA"});
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code and examples of the invalid device ID.

Comment: Restrictions are listened [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-identity-properties). If you encouter any issues you can create an issue on the skd repo like [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/783)

Comment: Can you share details on the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

`AddDeviceAsync()` expects a `Device` object, not a `DeviceConfig`, you likely want something along the lines of the below, I'm guessing:

```
        await this.deviceManager.AddDeviceAsync(d);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kartben, but I see that a bit of misunderstanding has existed.  "public async Task AddDeviceAsync(DeviceConfig deviceConfig)" is a method of deviceManager object so "this.deviceManager.AddDeviceAsync" row calls the AddDeviceAsync method. I try to save the device(device id = "ILICA") to the IoT hub given method. This method works successfully  for another device id for example "asd"

Comment: Right sorry, I got confused by the indentation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client; // namespace
using DeviceClient device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionstring");
```